# 50MB file taking too long to read in python

Tags: python, pandas, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to analyse a simple but "large" (52MB) .ped file I generated from a 1000genomes project .vcf file: it has 107 lines and 248189 columns. I do not care for the first 6 cols, and the ones I am interested in contain only letters, 'A','C','G','T', for which I need to calculate their frequencies. It is either only one of them or a combination of two (e.g. A,A,A,C,A,A,C,...). The thing is: I am not being able to load this whole file as the memory usage goes from 7GB to 16GB (which I can't understand since the file is only 52MB large), so I tried another approach.

The columns complement each other, so col 6 and 7 represent the same thing, 8 and 9, 10 and 11, so only really need to import two cols at a time in order to analyse this file. By creating a dict, I would be able to avoid loading the whole file, keep the necessary info and for that I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

def main(end):
    for col in range(6,end,2):
        allels = pd.read_csv('filtered_conv.ped',sep = '\t',header=None, usecols=[(col), (col+1)])
        allel_1 = allels[col].value_counts().rename_axis('Nb').reset_index(name='counts')
        allel_2 = allels[col+1].value_counts().rename_axis('Nb').reset_index(name='counts')
```

And for the dict I am using this inside the loop:

```
        if len(allel_1['counts']) == 2 and len(allel_2['counts']) == 2: 
            alt_nb = allel_1['Nb'][1]
            alt_c = allel_1['counts'][1]+allel_2['counts'][1]
        elif len(allel_1['counts']) == 2:
            alt_nb = allel_1['Nb'][1]
            alt_c = allel_1['counts'][1]
        else: 
            alt_nb = allel_2['Nb'][1]
            alt_c = allel_2['counts'][1]

        info = {'ref_Nb':allel_1['Nb'][0],
            'c_ref':(allel_1['counts'][0]+allel_2['counts'][0]),
            'alt_Nb':allel_1['Nb'][1] if len(allel_1['Nb']) == 2 else allel_2['Nb'][1],
            'c_alt':alt_c}
        freq_count.append(info)
```

And although it works, running this for cols 6 to 240 takes 30 seconds, so it would take about 8 hours to complete this process.

```
freq_count = []
start_time = time.time()
main(240)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Is there any other way to do this? I saw some other SO answers but categorizing the data (...dtype='category') increased this time from 33 to 38sec and I am not sure what else to do...

Comment: the reason this is so slow is probably because you read the file inside your for loop. I recommend you to move it outside the loop and use `allels = allels.copy()` if you need to make sure allels doesn't change. (in your case I believe it's not needed)

Comment: @Aking But if I do this outside of the for loop, how can I read only 2 cols at a time? I ask this because outside of the for loop I tried reading the whole file but to no avail...

Comment: it will be faster to read all the columns and run on them yourself.
pandas will read the entire file each time and return to you only the selected columns when you use `usecols`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all rows just contain 6 meta columns to skip, and then 248183 colums where every value can only be 'A','C','G' and 'T'? And the file is tab-separated?

```
with open('filtered_conv.ped') as file:
    # read line by line
    for line in file:
        # skip chars until 5 tabs were found
        tab_count = 0
        while tab_count < 5:
            if next(line) == "\t":
                tab_count += 1
        # iterate over characters
        for next_char in line:
            # do something in case A C G or T is found, ' \t and \n are skipped
            if next_char == "A":
                // do something
            elif next_char == "C":
                // do something
            elif next_char == "G":
                // do something
            elif next_char == "T":
                // do something
```

If you need a progress bar you can use tqdm like so:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
...

# read line by line
for line in tqdm(file):
   ...
```